# Google Maps URL parameter (saddr) link does not open after href replace

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

This a continuation from the discussion from this page: [Geolocation Google Maps Links jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451282/geolocation-google-maps-links-jquery)

I require the saddr to be set via navigator.geolocation when the user clicks on the link. I am able to achieve this via the code below, but after replacing the href, the link does not work. If I past the created link into the address bar it opens Google Maps and plots the correct course, but otherwise the link does not work.

I presume the href is getting replaced everytime the link is pressed. How would I go about having the link open at the end of the script?

EDIT: Solution provided by Duncan, working script is now displayed

```
    $("a.geo").click(function(e) {               
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($.proxy(getLoc, $(this)));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        });

        function getLoc(position) {                     
            var geoLat = position.coords.latitude;
            var geoLon = position.coords.longitude;
            document.location.href = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + geoLat + "," + geoLon + "&daddr=35.662296,139.765854&dirflg=w&sensor=true";

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So isn't what you really want to do, to update the current page location to be *"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + geoLat + "," + geoLon + "&daddr=35.662296,139.765854&dirflg=w&sensor=true"*

Instead of triggering the click event from a function that's called from within the click event handler (complicated, recursive), why not just do:

```
document.location.href = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + geoLat + "," + geoLon + "&daddr=35.662296,139.765854&dirflg=w&sensor=true";
```

Comment: If you remove that it the script doesn't fire at all and the default link fires. Add it back in, the script fires, replaces the href with the correct URL but the link will not fire.

Comment: hadn't realised how the functions were connected, new answer

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
$(a.geo).trigger('click');
```

with

```
$("a.geo").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Alas no dice. That was also a mistake, had copied an edited version of the code, whilst I was looking for a solution. Version I was usually working on had $(this). Code above edited.